# How can I make "Leave a comment" translation ready?

Tags: translation

I can't get this line of code translation ready.

```
<?php 
  comment_form(array ('title_reply' => 'Leave a comment')); 
?>
```

Thank you very much! Best wishes,
Pierre

Answer (score 2):

What about this way?

```
<?php 
  comment_form(array ('title_reply' => __('Leave a Reply'))); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be put to the translation function.

```
<?php comment_form(array ('title_reply' => __('Leave a comment', 'mytextdomain'))); ?>
```

Or use WordPress translation:

```
<?php comment_form(array ('title_reply' => __('Leave a comment'))); ?>
```